# C# program,with tostring() or not,which is better

Tags: c#, .net, string

a C# program, as you see , var month is defined as int, someone said without .tostring() is better, it should remove redundant call, now it is:`str= "0" + Month;`
 but i think it's not good .which one is better? why? thanks!(ps:my first question in stackoverflow)

```
string strM = string.Empty;
if ( Month < 10 )
    strM = "0" + Month.ToString ( );
    //strM = "0" + Month; which is better?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use .tostring, but not as shown.

```
    using System;
    class example {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int Month =5;
            Console.WriteLine(Month.ToString("00"));
        }
    }
```

http://ideone.com/LCwca

Outputs: 05

Answer (score 8):

Use string format instead:

```
string strM = string.Format("{0:00}", Month);
```

Test:

```
Month: 1 => strM: "01"
Month: 12 => strM: "12"
```

For more string format tips check [this](http://idunno.org/archive/2004/07/14/122.aspx).

Comment: thank you ,but i think  Month.ToString("00")  is better,it needn't call Class string

Answer (score 0):

As for your question other part, there is no difference, only clarity (style) of the code. Which to use it up to you. If you want to make an accent on that `Month` is not a `string` then you can add `.ToString()`. If this is obvious, like with `if ( Month < 10 )`, so you can see one line above comparison with `int`, hence `Month` is definetely not a `string` you can omit `.ToString()` call since it will be done automatically.